# Java Generics + Class name in String format

Tags: java, generics, apache-commons-dbutils

Below is running fine:

```
ResultSetHandler<List<MyClass>> h = new BeanListHandler<MyClass>(MyClass.class);
```

Issue is that `MyClass` is hard-coded. Above line is at centralized location and hence hard-coding is bad.

I have fully qualified class name of `MyClass` i.e. `com.company.vo.MyClass`

Now I want to generate above `ResultSetHandler` by converting incoming String to actual class.

Please help, I have tried:

```
Class<?> classObj = Class.forName("com.company.vo.MyClass");
ResultSetHandler<List<classObj>> h = new BeanListHandler<classObj>(classObj.class);
```

Which throws:

```
classObj cannot be resolved to a type
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You can't do that. Generics have no business at runtime. You've to know the class name at compile time.

Comment: As Rohit Jain points out, that's not possible. Compiler needs to know the exact class at compile time. Alternative: `ResultSetHandler<List<Object>>` should work for your purpose, although not type-safe.

Comment: What @RohitJain was reffering to is called *type erasure*. Look at this link: [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Comment: I'm not sure whether type erasure is an issue here. What does `query.getResultMapperClass()` return *exactly*, and what is the error message *exactly*? The call should probably be `new BeanListHandler<...>(classObj) ` (without the `.class`) anyhow.

Comment: Maybe guarantee that the class implements a given interface `IFoo`. Then have `Class<? extends IFoo> classObj = ...`. Then you can do `ResultSetHandler<List<? extends IFoo>> h = new BeanListHandler<List<? extends IFoo>>(classObj);`. Having `IFoo` contain all of the methods that exist in the class that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoded types are not bad. They are the essence of generics. The purpose of generics is to provide a better type check at `compile time`.  If you want to use `ResultSetHandler` with lists of different types, think about to use a common base class or interface of these types.